# Is there any way to dump boolean object in Cloud BigTable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I have certain usecase where api service are retrieving BigTable rows using rowKey. The issue I'm going through is api service is trying to retrieve some columns with boolean value and doing boolean comparison in front-end side. Since BigTable doesn't support that datatype. The front-end service comparison part is not working as expected. I'm using the below code to store boolean value in BigTable.

```
                    Boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean(newImageMap.get(Key).toString());
                    SetCell setCell = SetCell.newBuilder()
                            .setFamilyName(Utility.COLUMN_FAMILY)
                            .setColumnQualifier(Utility.str_to_bb(Key,StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                            .setTimestampMicros(yearAgoMillis)
                            .setValue(ByteString.copyFrom(Bytes.toBytes(value)))
                        //  .setValue(Utility.str_to_bb(String.valueOf(value),StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                            .build();
```

But the boolean value is stored as string in BigTable. You can see the stored value in below snapshot.
Let me know in case there is a way-out to handle this type of use-cases.
[boolean-value-ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckngd.png)

Comment: I've not first hand experience with Bigtable, but I won't change the data layer if the problem is the frontend. What about fixing it there or in the apis ? You could also try to use 1 as true and "empty" as false from the db but I don't know if this will fix your fe without knowing the exact impelentation

Comment: I can totally understand the part you are trying to say, but the problem with that is you can't go to each and every api and make the changes in the front-end accordingly. The application is so huge and not possible for us to back-track that part. So I'm going for alternate part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumping boolean object in BigTable is not possible as BigTable doesn't support boolean datatype. Rather I will suggest you to make the changes in your driver code and type-case the datatype to suitable form and send it to front-end side, which would be more suitable. For that you have to pre-identify the boolean datatype from source end and stored it as configuration which will be an input to  driver code.
Let me know in case this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

so there are two parts to this: working with the existing boolean string values you have and converting the current setup to be easier to work with.

To work with the current setup, you can just compare your results against a "true" and "false" string. This seems to not be what you want to do based on your discussion in the comments with Pievis.

So to convert the current setup:
You should use 0 as false and 1 as true (or you can leave empty as false) This will be more efficient for space. And then to convert all of your existing values, you'd have to do a full table scan filtering on the value "true" and then update those cells to be 1 and one where you filter on the value "false" where you delete those cells.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's what I thought earlier, but the front-end guys are not ready to make all that changes in their side. So I'm just stuck with this part.

Comment: Are you able to modify your database in-place as I outlined using a scan with a value filter?

Comment: As per current architectural rules, I can't modify the existing record which will impact the application.

Comment: You could create a new column to use that stores the data as you migrate everything over to the new format.

Comment: But that would result in condition level changes in front-end side